# ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, python-requests, betfair

I am trying the following sample code from the [betfair api](https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Example+Requests):

```
import requests
import json

url="https://api.betfair.com/betting/json-rpc"
header = { 'X-Application' : appKey,  'X-Authentication' : sessionToken, 'content-type' : 'application/json' }
jsonrpc_req='{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/listCompetitions", "params": {"filter":{ "eventTypeIds" : [1]  }}, "id": 1}'
print json.dumps(json.loads(jsonrpc_req), indent=3)
print " "
response = requests.post(url, data=jsonrpc_req, headers=header)
print json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=3)
```

I keep getting `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`.

Comment: Please show the complete traceback, not just the string of the error message. Otherwise, how could we know which of the multiple calls to `json.loads` is going wrong?

Comment: Also, this can't be your whole script, or you'd get `NameError: name 'appKey' is not defined` before you even get that far. Presumably you don't want to give us your API key and other credentials, but that means (if it's the last `loads` that's failing) you'll have to give us the contents of the `response.text`.

Comment: As a side note, why have you manually encoded `jsonrpc_req` as a JSON string, instead of just creating a `dict` and then calling `json.dumps` on it? The way you've done it should work just as well, but it's less readable, harder to debug, easier to break during maintenance, etc.

Comment: @abarnert, added response.text, I am new to json so basically just using provided examples on the betfair site, if you can show me better ways to do it feel free.

Comment: If their own sample code doesn't actually work, with no changes whatsoever, and everyone who looks at it can see that they're giving you the wrong URL… most likely the best thing to do is contact their support. Even if you've got some kind of free, no-support-included developer account, I'll bet they have either some way to contact them and/or a public forum for users to help each other. Either of those will help you more than random people on SO who've never heard of betfair and can't do much more than help you figure out that betfair's web service is broken…

Comment: It also might be worth checking whether their "REST" API (which isn't actually REST, but… whatever) at https://api.betfair.com/exchange/betting/rest/v1.0 (as seen [here](https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Getting+Started+with+API-NG)) works, even if the JSON-RPC one doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Hazarding a guess here:

https://api.betfair.com/betting/json-rpc is returning a 404 when making a straight `GET`. You can see the result in the browser too. A good API returns the proper error code (401 or 403) if it's a header problem. Are you sure you're calling the correct endpoint?

To troubleshoot, we'll need more info. What's the result of changing your last line to:

```
print response.text
```

Looking at your update, you're seeing the same thing as me: `The requested resource (/betting/json-rpc) is not available.`

Either you're sending the wrong header in your `POST` or, more likely, calling the wrong url. Doing a little digging, I think the correct one is:

https://api.developer.betfair.com/betting/json-rpc

Comment: @PadraicCunningham see update -- I think you had the wrong url.

Comment: I was using the url that is provided in the example but obviously it is not the correct one! Thanks.

Comment: getting "You don't have permission to access /svn/betting/json-rpc
on this server" now.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yeah, not sure about that. I think you need to go read through their (awful) API docs and find out what's going on. You can use a tool like [POSTMAN](http://getpostman.com) to help.

Comment: thanks and yes the docs are pretty bad, a lot of their code has syntax errors so really helpful when starting out.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: If their docs are full of syntax errors, I wouldn't be too surprised that they're also full of incorrect URLs…

Comment: Even if this doesn't solve the problem, you've definitely identified it, and done about as much digging as anyone can do from outside, so… +1. I think it's time for the OP to contact betfair support now.

Comment: One more thing to try: https://api.developer.betfair.com/betting/json-rpc/v1 (with that `v1` on the end), as seen in the first example [here](https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Getting+Started+with+API-NG).

Comment: @abarnert, getting 403, permission denied error. I think there must be some issue with my appKey. I will contact betfair and see what the story is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Betfair github](https://github.com/betfair/API-NG-sample-code/blob/master/python/ApiNgDemoJsonRpc.py) code seems to be more current - I've just tried the Python example code on their  account and it worked for me.  You'll need to set the the appKey and sessionToken in a similar manner to the answer to your previous, closely [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702601/accessing-betfair-api-to-get-horse-prices/20720157#20720157). I would ignore the out of date example code you originally referenced.